# Create a iPad Simulator with iOS version 11.3.1

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I received an Apple review comment says that they found an issue in my App when they run it on a iPad with iOS version 11.3.1.

I tried my App on an iPad simulator with iOS 11.3 and 11.4 (beta) but the issue was not reproduced.

What I want to do now is to test my App on a simulator with the exact version of iOS mentioned in Apple's review comment - that is 11.3.1

However, I found that iOS 11.3.1 is not available to me through xcode's components dialog - please refer to the screen capture image below for details.

[image]

**So my question is: how can I create an iPad simulator with iOS 11.3.1 ?**

*The xcode version that I am using right now is 9.4 beta downloaded from Apple developer center. I also tried xcode version 9.3.1 downloaded from Apple app store. Neither of it gives me iOS 11.3.1 - This line is added through edit after I read Roshan's answer. Thanks to Roshan.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there was no iOS 11.3.1 simulator released.  iOS 11.3.1 was a device-only update.  I would expect any issues related to iOS 11.3.1 to also appear with either iOS 11.3 or iOS 11.4, so those should be sufficient.